# react bootstrap hook function insert to react export class

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-typescript

Any idea for modal component without using hooks, and use it inside another, class-based component?

```
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question doesn't make sense.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: @MattMorgan Hello there, I updated my question

Comment: i don't understand the question.

Comment: Are you asking how to write this component without using hooks, and use it inside another, class-based component?

Comment: @MattMorgan yes, how can I do this? any idea ?

Comment: Please update your question so it's clear, and I'm sure someone will help you.

Comment: this isn't a hook, this is a component, and you can use is like `<Example />`. so i don't really get the question. the only hook i see here is `useState`.

Comment: `render(<Example />);` is there just for example right? or is this your problem? it should be `export default Example`

Answer (score 1):

```
// example.js
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}> Launch demo modal </Button>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>Save Changes</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

```
// other-component.js
import Example from './example.js'

function OtherComponent() {
  return (
    <>
       <Example />
    </>
  );
}
```